# org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection: com.abc.entities.Packages.protectedItems column: account_id?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am facing below error when doing ManyToMany mapping with Composite Keys -

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
> default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for
> collection:
> com.abc.reports.entities.Packages.protectedItems column:
> account_id

I have gone through other sof post with similar error but nothing much help full for my case I could find there. This error has become a blocker for my release and so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Basically I have compound primary key in both the tables and have a join table to map the ManyToMany relationship.

My Entity classes and Embeddable classes are as below -

**Compound Keys**

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class PackageId implements Serializable {

    private String accountId;

    private Long packageId;

}

@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class ProtectedItemsId implements Serializable {

    private String accountId;

    private Long protectedItemId;

}
```

**Entity Classes**.
**Packages.class**.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Packages {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PackageId packageId;

    private String packageName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "packageItemsList")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<ProtectedItems> protectedItems;
    
}
```

**ProtectedItems.class**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProtectedItems implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ProtectedItemsId protectedItemId;

    private String protectedItemName;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="jt_packages_protected_items",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="accountId", insertable=false, updatable=false), @JoinColumn(name="protectedItemId", insertable=false, updatable=false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="accountId", insertable=false, updatable=false), @JoinColumn(name="packageId", insertable=false, updatable=false)} )
    private List<Packages> packageItemsList;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "protectedItemsList")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<StreamMappings> streamMappings;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ProtectedItems{" +
                "protectedItemId=" + protectedItemId +
                ", protectedItemName='" + protectedItemName +
                ", packageItemsList=" + packageItemsList.hashCode() +
                ", streamMappings=" + streamMappings +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The hibernate error message is little helpful in identifying the problem even after looking at the above classes.
I can add the DB schema if that helps, but think it's not necessary. Like said any help will be greatly appreciated as it will let me proceed with my release schedule.

Comment: both `Packages` and `ProtectedItems` have composite primary key, and HBN expects that mapping table `jt_packages_protected_items` contains `4` columns but you have only `3`, quick dirty fix there is to create `view` based on `jt_packages_protected_items` with `4` columns, another option is to rethink model.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov, you are right. the problem was w.r.t join table.
Join Table of Package and ProtectedItems has 3 columns → ( account_id, package_id and protected_item_id).
Hibernate seems to be expecting 4 columns. So I changed it to → ( p_account_id, package_id and pi_account_id, protected_item_id) and changed the mappings accordingly and it worked.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov - 
But i would prefer to keep 3 columns only as it was initially and make Hibernate accept this table design as it would fit my business case and not allow any data issues latter. Basically the account_id in all three tables refer to the same entity. Any suggestions will be greatly helpful on how to keep 3 columns and still make hibernate happy about it.